# Converting datetime object to timestamp and back gives me a different time

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I have encountered this problem today and I don't have an explanation for it.

I have a Python datetime object:

```
dt = datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 31, 18, 30, 48, tzinfo=<FixedOffset '-04:00'>)
```

which, to my understanding is 18:30 in a time zone offset from UTC by 4 hours.
I then tried to convert it to timestamp like so:

```
epo = time.mktime(dt.timetuple()) and get back 1333247448.0.
```

However, when I try to convert it back to make sure it's correct using date

```
time.datetime.fromtimestring(epo),
```

I get back

```
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 31, 19, 30, 48)
```

Notice that time is 19 not 18.

Can anybody tell me why it's doing that?

Comment: Please check your `epo`: `date -d @1333247448 -u` is `Sun Apr  1 02:30:48 UTC 2012` ???

Comment: I completely forgot about daylight savings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
time.localtime(epo)
```

instead of

```
time.datetime.fromtimestring(epo)
```